# Ruby hash of arrays from array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have the following array

```
a=[["kvm16", "one-415"], ["kvm16", "one-416"], ["kvm5", "one-417"]]
```

I would like to convert this to a hash that looks like this

```
{"kvm5"=>["one-417"], "kvm16"=>["one-417", "one-416"]}
```

everything I have tried squashes the value.

```
v=Hash[ a.collect do |p| [p[0], [ p[1] ] ] end ]
=> {"kvm5"=>["one-417"], "kvm16"=>["one-416"] }
```

I was thinking I could check to see if v[p[0]] is an array, but the variable isn't defined inside this block.

Is there a clean way to accomplish what I am looking for?

Comment: you mean `{"kvm16"=>["one-415", "one-416"], "kvm5"=>["one-417"]}`?

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, you have to do it yourself, I'm afraid.

```
a = [["kvm16", "one-415"], ["kvm16", "one-416"], ["kvm5", "one-417"]]

h = a.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), memo|
  (memo[k] ||= []) << v
end

h # => {"kvm16"=>["one-415", "one-416"], "kvm5"=>["one-417"]}
```

Or, if you're on older ruby (1.8.x):

```
h = {}
a.each do |k, v|
  (h[k] ||= []) << v
end

h # => {"kvm16"=>["one-415", "one-416"], "kvm5"=>["one-417"]}
```

Comment: undefined method `each_with_object'

Comment: unfortunately I am unable to move to 1.9.3 in this instance.  I am at ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux] Pasting the above code results in 
    [["kvm16", "one-415"], ["kvm16", "one-416"], ["kvm5", "one-417"]]

Comment: a.each { |k,v| if h[k].is_a?(Array) ; h[k].push(v);else;h[k] = [v];end }

=> [["kvm16", "one-415"], ["kvm16", "one-416"], ["kvm5", "one-417"]]

I must be missing something fundamental

Comment: Just copy/paste exactly, don't retype.

Answer (score 4):

Let's see some functional approaches. This is a common abstraction, you can find it as [Enumerable#map_by](http://rdoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/master/Enumerable#map_by-instance_method) in Facets:

```
require 'facets'
hs.map_by { |k, v| [k, v] }
#=> {"kvm16"=>["one-415", "one-416"], "kvm5"=>["one-417"]}
```

This pattern replaces the cumbersome `group_by` + `map` + `Hash`:

```
Hash[hs.group_by(&:first).map { |k, gs| [k, gs.map(&:last)] }]
#=> {"kvm16"=>["one-415", "one-416"], "kvm5"=>["one-417"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

this has it.  in the face of not having each_with_object in my version of ruby and some googleze I arrived at

```
{}.tap{ |h| items.each{ |item| h[item.id] = item } }
=> {"kvm5"=>["one-417"], "kvm16"=>["one-415", "one-416"]}
```

mucho thanks to Sergio for getting me thinking along that line